# Bootstrap carousel: slide up vertically centered text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-carousel

I've centered text inside carousel items with `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`. It works fine but when slide changes the text inside it shows at the top first and only then centered.

Here is my code - **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a76d2q7u/2/)**

How to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any margins set. I added some to item and it seemed to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/a76d2q7u/3/

```
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
.carousel{
  height:200px;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 17% 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works but only with single line. I need to center text with different number of lines.

Comment: and without changing carousel height.